# How to connect to a remote Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using  [C9.io](http://C9.io)

Here my server:

```
var io = require('socket.io');


  var socket = io.listen(8080, { /* options */ });
  socket.set('log level', 1);


  socket.on('connection', function(socket) {

        console.log("connected");

    socket.on('message1', function(data) {
          socket.emit("message1",JSON.stringify({type:'type1',message: 'messageContent'}));

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {

         console.log("diconnected");

    });
  });
```

When i run it generate this url: https://xxx-c9-smartytwiti.c9.io and tell me that my code is running in this URL.

**Note**: xxx is my workspace

What i did in my client:
Connect to "https://xxx-c9-smartytwiti.c9.io:8080/"
....

Then i get this error on console(firefox browser):

```
cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxx-c9-smartytwiti.c9.io:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1406060495041. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

**Note**: when i host my server locally it works perfectly.

Seems like c9.io using a proxy or a firewall, but how can i test my code written in the c9.io remotely ?

**UPDATE**

According to ruben's response i've changed my server, and it works when my socket.io-client hosted in C9 but still can't get this working on remote client(i've also hosted the client in my FTP but same result):

```
// module dependencies
var http = require("http"),
    sio  = require("socket.io");

// create http server
var server = http.createServer().listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP),

// create socket server
io = sio.listen(server);

// set socket.io debugging
io.set('log level', 1);


io.set('origins', '*:*');


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


  socket.emit('news', { message: 'Hello world!' });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
  });

});
```

Looks like  the origin configuration has been ignored, i'm also not sure about C9.io..

suggestions ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using port 8080. Instead try using `process.env.IP` and `process.env.PORT`. In addition it is important to not specify a port on the domain to your workspace. The default port (port 80) is forward to the internal port of your container on `c9.io`. If you connect to the default port by not specifying it you won't have a problem with cross domain security.

See also:
https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/native-websockets-support/

Ruben - Cloud9 Support

Comment: Thanks Ruben, now my client code  working in c9, but still getting "cross-Origin Request Blocked" on remote access, please see my update

Answer (score 2):

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) requires that your client code and WebSocket server be hosted at the same URL and port. You can find specific examples of ways to integrate them in the [Socket.IO docs](http://socket.io/docs/). Here's their example of how to do it using the built-in HTTP server. Instead of giving Socket.IO a hostname/port, you give it your webserver object:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, can you provide me a link to the doc, i can't find what i'm looking for..

Comment: What web server are you using?